# How can I sort the results of a recursive directory grep search (grep -rl )?

Tags: linux, grep

I want to sort the results of `grep -rl 'string' .` by create date or modification date.

Comment: what does 'chronologically' mean? Based on timestamps in the strings printed by grep? Based on the file's latest modification times? Please flesh out your question with an example of what you're getting, and what you'd rather see.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -cmin -90 |xargs ls -1t |xargs grep -l "pattern"
```

- **find** does recursive part and initial cut-off to ensure you don't get too many files (changed in last 90 minutes here)
- **ls** does the sort (**-t**) and output one file by line (**-1**)
- **grep** list the names of file that match the pattern

And of course **xargs** is what passes output of one command as parameters to another. Which is why you want to pre-filter the list with find to avoid having too many.

Comment: You don't need `-1`. `ls` does that automatically whenever the output is not going to a terminal.

Comment: Good point. It was easier to troubleshoot it with that option explicit as I built the pipeline.